# Web API authentication like Facebook, Twitter and Google

Tags: c#, .net, authentication

I need to develop an external API, and I want to implement authentication with a client ID and a secret key just like Facebook, Twitter, Google and Microsoft do.

I have read some tutorials about OAuth2, but his generated token is temporary, and clients need to pass the username and password to get a token.

So, what I want is to give a client ID and a secret key to every client that will use my API, and they should pass this data on every method they call. Before returning the result, API checks if the request is valid.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: So what is your problem? Just generate a random byte array with [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb9c8c67(v=vs.110).aspx) convert it to base64 with [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx) and store that string into db per each user. This string will be an API key

Comment: If you want standard implementation its OAuth2 protocol.. for .net there are multiple server implementation you can use.https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is 'Basic Authentication'. Here's a very simple tutorial to follow in order to fulfill your requirements: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/basic-authentication-in-webapi

It goes without saying that you should set your site to force https so that the credentials in request header are encrypted.

Comment: Thank you, Basic Authentication was what I was looking for!